# How can I configure the power button to shutdown the computer

Tags: release-loki, shutdown

In the power settings there is no option to perform the shutdown action when a I press the power button. I only see the options to suspend and hibernate or do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit `logind.conf` in `/etc/systemd`, and change the line as shown below (remember to unhash it):

```
HandlePowerKey=poweroff
```

Now I'm on Manjaro, so I can't confirm if it works, but it should.

Comment: I just tried this and it does not seem to work ... still does a sleep ... mind you ... I am not on a laptop so that could cause a difference

Comment: There is the option, I tried that but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

Open terminal. Type: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Hit Enter

After installing dconf-tools, on screen (desktop), click on `Applications` (top left of the screen), then find and click on `dconf Editor` (normally the logo is a Magnifying glass with a checked red box)

In **dconf Editor**, go to: `org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > power`

Click on the value of `button-power` and choose `shutdown`

Answer (score 0):

You could put this command in the terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action shutdown`

It should force your dconf to be set for shutdown when power button is pressed.

Comment: also tries this ...however

Comment: I guess they have removed the shutdown functionality for the power button. You should notify the bug tracker of elementary, they might tell you another way or simply add this feature for the next update.

Comment: The command does not work, I also tried the dconf-editor, the option shutdown does not appear.